# Approximate $\int_t^{\infty}e^{-\delta(s-t)}\omega(s)\text{ds}$, with the restriction that just $\omega(t)$,...,$\omega^{(n)}(t)$ are known.

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the following integral: $$\int_t^{\infty}e^{-\delta(s-t)}\omega(s)\text{ds},$$ where $t\geq 0$ represents the current time, $\delta>0$ is a *fixed* parameter representing the exponential decay rate, and $\omega:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a *given* smooth bounded function, whose infinite derivatives are also bounded and with none derivative null.

I need to approximate the value of this integral with the *restriction* that I only have information about the actual $n$-first derivatives $\omega(t)$, $\dot{\omega}(t)$,... ,$\omega^{(n)}(t)$, with $n\geq 0$.

Recursive integration by parts leads to
$$\int_t^{\infty}e^{-\delta(s-t)}\omega(s)\text{ds} = -\frac{1}{\delta}\omega(t) + \frac{1}{\delta^2}\dot{\omega}(t)\pm...+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\delta^{n+1}}\omega^{(n)}(t)+\mathcal{O}_n,$$ where $$\mathcal{O}_n=\frac{1}{\delta^{n+2}}\int_t^{\infty}e^{-\delta(s-t)}\omega^{(n+1)}(s)\text{ds}.$$

What happens is the following:

Consider a fixed big $\delta$ (say $\delta\gg1$). Then the residual $\mathcal{O}_n$ is expected to be small as $1/\delta^{n+2}$ is continuously decreasing with respect to $n$. This indicates that, if $\delta\gg1$, then the integral can be well-approximated by neglecting $\mathcal{O}_n$ and, furthermore, the approximation may work better if we have more information about the actual derivatives, i.e. if we can made $n$ arbitrarily large.

However, for a fixed small $\delta$ (say $\delta\ll 1$), then the residual is continuously increasing with respect to $n$. This indicates that the approximation does not work as $\mathcal{O}_n$ is expected to be big. Furthermore, the approximation may work even worse if we have more information about the actual derivatives!, i.e. making $n$ arbitrarily large.

Could anyone provide an alternative analysis explaining this issue?. Clearly, $\delta\gg 1$ is needed in order to approximate the integral with this expansion. But, for me is strange because it is just the exponential decay-rate... So why it should be bigger than 1 and not any other number?

Comment: I wonder what $n \to \infty$ is actually supposed to mean here. The way it is written it seems that $n$ depends on $\omega$, so to let $n \to \infty$, one has to vary $\omega$, but then one cannot make much non-trivial comparisons between the integrals for different $n$ and $\omega$ anyway. Please clarify.

Comment: Well if $n$ is fixed, the dichotomy $a<1$ versus $a>1$ disappears. What you have is that the error term $\mathcal {O}_n$ decreases as $a$ increases, continuously depending on $a$, without anything special happening at $a=1$; which makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. You have helped me to clarify this question. I have rewritten it again in order to avoid confusions. In any case, even for the case of $n$ fixed (and $\delta$ unfixed), it does not make perfect sense for me. I am asking for an alternative analysis that clarifies this behavior. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest finding a more descriptive title for your question.

Comment: Remark that $\mathcal{O}_n$ depends not only on $\delta$ and $n$, but also on $\omega^{(n+1)}$ and $s$. It might very well be that that factor in the integral "cancels out" the effect of the $\delta^{-n-2}$. Maybe try some easy examples (say $\omega(t) = \sin(t)$ and $\sin^2(t)$) and see what actually happens in those error terms.

Comment: Thank you again. I will find the analytic expression for some simple examples, but I'm pretty sure that the effect of $\delta^{n-2}$ will not be canceled. I have performed different comparisons with MatLab and, in all of them, the value of the integral is well approximated for $\delta \gg1$ and badly approximated for $\delta\ll 1$